# Displaying parent div horizontally beyond width of page

Tags: php, html, css, width, horizontal-scrolling

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

The height of the child class is 20% and the width 200px.

What I'm wondering is how to make it so that when I have, for example, 20 parent divs it is set up so that they are all displayed horizontally, beyond the width of the page, so that I have to scroll left or right to view the data. At the moment it fills the width of the page and starts the next parent div underneath the first one so that I have to scroll vertically and I can't fathom how to rectify this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean 20 child div's will be displayed horizontally?

Comment: Yes, one after another, at the minute 5 will be displayed horizontally and the 6th will be underneath the first because it can't go past the width of the page, i'm wondering how to get around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you need to create a parent container, and then assign a `overflow-x: scroll` css rule to it. You will also need to assign a `display: inline-block` rule to your `parent` class. You also need to apply white-space: nowrap;.

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/qujyunn4/

```css
.wrapper {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.parent {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    border: red solid thin;
    margin-right: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="child">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
      </div>
      <div class="child">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this hasn't worked, they're still not going beyond the width of the page

Comment: @marc-audet I fear I've been misunderstood. 20 parent divs displayed horizontally but the children are columns of 5 to the height of the page.